# Getting 404 error when changing route from [Route("[controller]")] to [Route("api/[controller]")]

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I'm using *ASP.NET Core with Angular* template. Here's the screenshot of the template.

[image]

In the `WeatherForecastController.cs` controller, I have the following code. When I make HTTP GET request to  I'm able to get the response.

```
namespace Project1.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
    }
}
```

But when I change the route from `[Route("[controller]")]` to `[Route("api/[controller]")]` and I make HTTP GET request to `https://localhost:44452/api/weatherforecast` I getting error status 404 `Cannot GET /api/weatherforecast`

```
namespace Project1.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you change the context in the *proxy.conf.js* to match the changes you did on the backend?

Comment: @R.Richards - I did not. After making this change as you suggested, It's working now. Thanks